# High Chart different color for one column

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts

[image]

I have highchart with the column data type is "Granules". This graph associated with a table Hasil.ini example

Hasil

| ...................| butiran |

| 2015/02/25  |    53    |

| 2015/03/01  |    66      |

| 2015/03/07  |    78      |

nah, I would like for each date has a different color for one type of column .. I hope you understand what I maksud..tolong help me, how to separate colors for one data column highchart .Thank You

Comment: You can make each data point its own series and assign the colors using the colors[] array?

Answer (score 2):

In the **y axixs** use the data variable like this

```
data: [
                {y: 53, color: 'red'}, 
                {y: 66, color: 'blue'}, 
                {y: 78, color: 'green'}, 
]
```

Hope this maybe helpfull to you

Answer (score 0):

This ismysource code of HighChart Jquery

$('#container').highcharts({
        data: {
            table: 'datatable'
        },
          chart: {
            type: 'column',
            margin: 75,
             options3d: {
                enabled: true,
                alpha: 15,
                beta: 15,
                depth: 50,
                viewDistance: 25
            }

```
    },
    colors: ['<?php echo $warna;?>'],
    title: {
        text: 'Grafik Perkembangan Hasil Pemeriksaan Pasien'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            depth: 44
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        max:<?php echo $data['batas_atas'];?>,
        min:<?php echo $data['batas_bawah'];?>,
        title: {
            text: 'Angka '
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                this.point.y + ' ' + this.point.name.toLowerCase();
        }
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Edit your question. Don"t use "Answer" button unless you are **answering** your question.. And see answer by @r.vengadesh.